# Group more records based on values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
contract_nr     id_supplier id_seller   id_vendor
01              1521        NULL        NULL
01              1521        2           NULL
01              NULL        NULL        538
02              NULL        NULL        154
02              NULL        NULL        159
03              2626        17          NULL
03              NULL        17          124
```

The result should be a grouped table with the category field based on these rules:

1. IF there is a id_supplier or id_seller other then NULL, then it is
   category1
2. IF there is only an id_vendor and id_supplier and id_seller is NULL,
   then it is category2

The result should look like this:

```
contract_nr     category
01              category1
02              category2
03              category1
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: you should use case when block

Comment: What if all are null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT contract_nr,
       CASE 
          WHEN SUM(id_supplier IS NOT NULL) + SUM(id_seller IS NOT NULL) >= 1 
             THEN 'category1'
          WHEN SUM(id_vendor IS NOT NULL) THEN 'category2'
          ELSE 'N/A'
       END   
FROM mytable
GROUP BY contract_nr;
```

In MySQL you can use `SUM` together with a boolean expression in order to find how many times a condition is satisfied within each group. Hence, using the predicate:

```
SUM(id_supplier IS NOT NULL) + SUM(id_seller IS NOT NULL) >= 1
```

we can test whether, for a given `contract_nr`, *at least one* record exists having *either* `id_supplier`, *or* `id_seller`, *or both* not null.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/BRI63189)

Comment: This answer is actually wrong as per the requirements given by the OP. In the second point it clearly states that if id_vendor is not null and id_supplier **and** id_seller are NULL, then category2. If OP thinks this is the right answer, then there is problem in the question

Comment: @GurV If the predicate of the second `WHEN` clause of the `CASE` expression is satisfied, this means that the corresponding predicate of the first `WHEN` clause is *not* satisfied. This means it is redundant to repeat the predicate of the first `WHEN` clause in the second `WHEN` clause.

Comment: Nope. First when has an **OR** check, second require an **AND** check. So, not so redundant.

Comment: @GurV There is *no* `OR` check in the *first* `WHEN`. If `SUM(id_supplier IS NOT NULL) + SUM(id_seller IS NOT NULL)` is not `> 1`  then it is equal to     `0`, this means both fields (`id_supplier`, `id_seller`) are `NULL` for all records that belong to the same `contract_nr` group.

Comment: Gosh I missed that, sorry. Then clearly your first `when` is wrong. See the question

Comment: @GurV The OP states *IF there is a id_supplier or id_seller other then NULL, then it is category1* in that case `SUM(id_supplier IS NOT NULL) + SUM(id_seller IS NOT NULL) > 1` is true. Where is the mistake?

Comment: *IF there is a id_supplier **or** id_seller other then NULL* - If I write expression in your way, it will be `sum(...) + sum(...) >= 1`. Further, your method can't be used even for `and` condition properly as there can be multiple non nulls in id_seller and none in id_supplier.

Comment: @GurV The remark about `>=1` was correct and I've edited my answer. My method seems to suit the OP just fine, otherwise he wouldn't have checked my answer as accepted. I'll stop here, I don't see any point in continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation paired with a `case` expression to check your required condition on the data:

```
select
    contract_nr,
    case
        when max(id_supplier) is not null 
                or max(id_seller) is not null
            then 'category1'
        when max(id_vendor) is not null
                and max(id_supplier) is null 
                and max(id_seller) is null
            then 'category2'
    end as category
from your_table
group by contract_nr;
```

It uses the fact the max returns maximum non null value in the aggregation group. If there are only nulls present in the group, then it will return a null.

Also note that it will return null in category if both the conditions do not meet. You may want to add an `else 'category3'` to the case to capture that.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/QUB34813)

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Answer (score 0):

Group by contract_nr then use `case when` and `count`(which excludes null value) to do this:

```
select
    contract_nr,
    case when count(id_supplier) = 0 and count(id_seller) = 0 and count(id_vendor) > 0 then 'category2'
         else 'category1'
    end as category
from yourtable
group by contract_nr
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69c4be/5) in sqlfiddle.